# Updating Cygwin and zsh causes permission problems

Tags: cygwin, zsh, setup

I updated my Cygwin installation for the first time after more than one year (running the cygwin setup program), and when I started my interactive zsh login shell, I quickly ran into various problems. The first one was that the commands in /usr/bin were not found anymore via the PATH. A quick check via my `.zshrc` revealed, that they indeed were not in my initial PATH anymore; I think they had been previously set in `/etc/zprofile`, but anyway,  I added the necessary PATH settings and was able to have a zsh where most commands worked.

Still, `man` did not work, complaining *man: can't open the manpath configuration file /etc/man_db.conf*. I verified that the file did exist, but it had the permissions 040. I changed the permissions to 444, and now the `man` command worked again.

Now I looked at `/etc/zprofile`. This file too had permissions 040, but more importantly, it had length zero! No wonder that my PATH was broken!

Of course I can edit this file and put it all definitions I need, but my main concern was why my /etc directory got these problems during the setup. Has anybody experienced something similar when updating Cygwin?

Comment: never. Any AV interfering ?

Comment: Windows Defender .... But it's hard to believe that this would cause that effect.